# Bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

Currently I'm self studying functional analysis, namely Hilbert spaces. In the text, the author gives the following remark:

> **Remark**: If $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space, then for every bounded linear operator
> $A\colon\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$ we have that the operator norm (or rather dual norm) is given by
> $$
> ||A||_\text{op}=\sup\{|\langle Ax,y \rangle|: ||x||\leq 1,||y||\leq 1\}.\tag{1}
> $$

My question is fairly straightforward: why is this remark true? I know one way of writing the operator norm for such a map is the following:
$$
||A||_\text{op}=\sup\{||Ax||:||x||\leq 1\}.\tag{2}
$$

But how does $(2)$ turn into $(1)$?

Comment: Exercise for you: $\lVert x\rVert=\sup_{\lVert y\rVert\leq1}\lvert\langle x,y\rangle\rvert$ for all $x\in\mathcal{H}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two norms. The first norm is the vector norm, which is written $\|x\|$.  For a Hilbert space, this is also the same as $\sqrt{\langle x, x, \rangle}$. The second norm is the operator norm. For a linear operator $f: Y \rightarrow Z$, where $Y,Z$ are both normed spaces, the norm of $f$ is written as
$$
\|f\|_{op} := \sup_{\|y\| \le 1} \|f(y)\|.
$$
The crucial thing here is that these two norms are one and the same on a Hilbert space when $x$ is viewed as a linear map $\mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $f_x(y) = \langle x, y \rangle$; that is, the vector norm of $x$ is the same as the operator norm of $f_x$, and thus:
$$\sup_{\|y\| \le 1} |\langle x, y \rangle| = \|x\|$$
This is a crucial property of how vector space duality works, and it is worthwhile for you to understand why this property holds.

Therefore, replacing $x$ with $Ax$, we similarly obtain $\sup_{\|y\| \le 1} |\langle Ax, y \rangle| = \|Ax\|$, and the equality that you wanted to show follows.

Comment: "is both the Hilbert space norm, but also the norm of $x$ when viewed as a linear functional over the dual; that is:$$\sup_{\|y\| \le 1} |\langle x, y \rangle| = \|x\|."$$ Can you explain this a little more?

Comment: I have expanded my answer further.

Comment: Great! Shouldn't it be mentioned $x$ (being viewed as a bounded linear functional on a Hilbert space) can be rewritten as such do due the Riesz representation theorem? Or is this not needed?

Comment: It is related, but technically not necessary. The Riesz representation theorem is a uniqueness result that says that every linear functional on a Hilbert space can be expressed as an inner product against a unique vector. This is in some sense the reverse of what we need for your question. For your question, we only need that the map $y \mapsto \langle x, y\rangle$ is a linear functional and its operator norm is $\|x\|$, and this does not depend on uniqueness.